# c# what wpf control to use for showing text file

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

Whats the best control to use in wpf applicaion for loading big text files into? And its not just simple as that, i need to be able to hightlight/change background/color of some lines. I was thinking of using RichTextBox.. but though i just come and ask what other people think.

**I dont need to edit the text, just highlight lines with errors**

EDIT: Ah i forgot to mention, text file content is processed by the program what will change the background color of some lines. Would be nice to give user a change to do that allso when the program failes to find some error lines.

EDIT2: The application is for parsing log files, so the files might be big, over 50 000 lines..

Comment: RichTextbox has ready made functionalities for you requirement. But, it's performance is quite bad when you are styling around over 5Mb file. It doesn't have inbuilt virtual mode. Probably you can extent that for you. If you are going to use it, first make sure that your happy with it's performance. I am not sure any .net control to recommend for large text file processing with styling.

Comment: Yes, you are quite right, i have 1MB file here for testing and it takes allready too long to load into the RichTextbox. What would be other solutions to use to make it faster?

Comment: What's the maximum file size you want to use there? I am not sure whether it can be optimized to use large text files. Turn off it's unwanted features like spell checking and see.

Comment: DocumentViewer is also a suitable control for you. I've never used it though, give it a go and see. If not, I think you have to find any other third party control for that ( as far as I know).

Comment: How about this : http://www.textpad.com/support/faq/csharp.html

Comment: @CharithJ, well i think the maximum of the maximum would be around 2MB not more..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't understand if you only want to display files or allow user to edit them.

Either way, maybe [ScintillaNET](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/) would be useful to you.

Well known text editor, Notepad++ uses Scintilla :)

You could grab notepad++ sources at http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/, but It's written in c++, so the API would be a bit different than in .NET.

**EDIT**

Notepad++ is capable of displaying files of around 100-200MB. If you need better than that, you would need to implement some kind of paging technology/virtual mode (do not load entire file, only the portion that would be displayed on the screen depending on current scrollbar position)

If Scintilla seems an overkill, then maybe you'd be better off with simply building a DataGrid. If log entries consist of several fields, these could become columns and would be even easier to read. If you want to go that route, first parse your log file into a List of LogEntry, then use databinding to bind to it. You could read your file incrementally as new lines get added for better user experience.

Comment: I actually dont need to edit them, just want to display them with some highlighted lines.

Comment: I just had a look into ScintillaNET codeplex control. It sounds really good. I think it's a good one to try.

Comment: Actually, It should work in VS2010: http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Installation . It's a WinForms control though, so you would have to enclose it in WindowsFormsHost as in http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-winforms-in-wpf

Comment: @hs2d I've seen people suggest AvalonEdit over ScintillaNET (haven't used it myself). It's pure WPF and is used in SharpDevelop. http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/AvalonEdit.ashx

Comment: @surfen, thnx. Testing AvalonEdit right now. Loads my 1MB file in a snap. Now just have to see if it suites my other needs. (:

Answer (score 1):

I think `RichTextBox` will be most appropriate in this case but as CharithJ said you cannot load whole log in to it at one time it will be too much performance hit.

What I would do in scenario like this is .. I will have a `Richtextbox` along with two small up and down buttons for kind of scroll. I will only load some text of log at one time let's say x number of characters. Once user clicks the up or down scroll button, I would remove some text from start and end depending on which button user have clicked, up or down and based on that I would remove some text from richbox and append some other.

Either you can do something like I suggested above, or one other way could be to extend the `RichTextBox` control and implement logic that only forwards a limited text to `RichTextBox` for display at a time. You can handle scroll related events to make changes in RichTextBox's content.

Comment: Yes, that's true. This is the only way to make it faster. But it may make your text highlighting logic quite complicated and it's not quite easy to implement this (at least for me).